# R ggsave dpi is always 72 in MacOS

Tags: r, macos, ggplot2, ggsave

I am using m1 Mac.
When I use ggsave to save a 300 dpi png or other formats, Mac always will convert it to 72     dpi.

For example,

```
library(tidyverse)
a <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) +
geom_point(size=2, shape=23)+
theme_bw(base_size = 11)

ggsave(filename = "figure1.png",
a,
width = 2.14, height = 1.51, dpi = 300,units = "in")
```

I searched very hard but there are few useful answers on the Internet. But I found if I add type = "cairo" in ggsave, I can have the right dpi 300 figures.

```
ggsave(filename = "figure2.png",
a,
width = 2.14, height = 1.51, dpi = 300,units = "in",
type = "cairo")
```

Do you know the reason for this problem? I am so confused even though I found the type = "cairo" trick.

Comment: Does the actual pixel dimensions change when you adjust the DPI? You are probably getting a larger image but the export function might not be setting the actual DPI header of the file. What are you using to check the DPI value?

Comment: I use Mac preview and PS to check the dpi, and both of them show 72 dpi. Actually the dimension is 642*453, if the figure is width = 2.14, height = 1.51, units = "in", it will be 300 dpi. But the figure size changed by Mac

Comment: I think that is an issue with mac preview not reading in the original dpi metadata generated by the default device. If you like, you can use Preview - Tools - Adjust Size to change the dpi metadata in a way that Mac will reference, without changing the underlying pixels.

Comment: See this similar question on RStudio Community that references how to examine the dpi metadata and see that mac Preview does not reference it: https://community.rstudio.com/t/ggplot2-ggsave-dpi-and-figure-size-woes/99816/6?u=jonspring

Comment: Hi Jon Spring,
thank you for your help. I change resolution to 300 in Preview - Tools - Adjust Size, width, and height changing automatically. Now the figure is 300dpi and width = 2.14, height = 1.51. 
I looked at the question  community.rstudio.com/t/ggplot2-ggsave-dpi-and-figure-size-woes/…   But I didnot understand.
So do you mean when i use PS or preview to open the figure, PS and preview make wrong assumption of width and height. When i change the dpi to 300, why is it become correct? thank you sooooo much!

Comment: Do I need to adjust size every time after I ggsave a figure? thank you.@JonSpring